# Is a passport required to cross Schengen borders?

Tags: schengen, passports

Once one is within the Schengen union.  Is it necessary to have one's passport crossing from one Schengen country into another? For example, a Paris tour bus provides a Brussels guided tour for the day.

Comment: Also [Can a non-EU national move between Schengen countries without a passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/96342/19400)

Answer (score 4):

In reality, no, but countries laws change on what documents you require to be lawfully in the country, for example, in Italy you must have your passport with you.
However, crossing from France to Belgium, you will not encounter a regular border check. I would always keep my passport with me while travelling cross-border. I’ve never crossed the French and Belgian border, I have crossed the French-Italian border hundreds of times, and a good amount of those times there have been suprise identity checks.
Best advice is better to be safe than sorry and carry a passport cross-border every time.

Comment: Various Schengen countries *require* people who want to cross borders to bring a passport or other ID document, and to present it to competent officials on demand. Just this weekend I was in a local train that had noticed posted because the line went from Germany through Switzerland.